# Issues using Firewire sound card with Thunderbolt adapter

Tags: audio, thunderbolt, firewire

I was using a [Saffire Pro 40](http://uk.focusrite.com/firewire-audio-interfaces/saffire-pro-40) card on a macbook via FireWire.
I now need to use it on a mac mini and it only has Thunderbolt ports and no Firewire.

I've got a Firewire to Thunderbolt adapter and power the sound card with a power supply, but it simply doesn't get listed in System Information.

The manufacture mentions it should work:

> Thunderbolt™ Compatible In common with all Focusrite Saffire
>   interfaces, Saffire PRO 40 is compatible with Thunderbolt ports via
>   the use of a FireWire to Thunderbolt adaptor (not included). An
>   external power supply is recommended for use in Thunderbolt
>   applications, particularly when using phantom power.

Has anyone else experienced this ? What should I check ?

How can I get a Saffire Pro 40 working via Thunderbolt on a mac mini ?

Comment: Is it an Apple TB>FW, or 3rd party?

Comment: It's an Apple one, bought from an Apple Store. Is there any way I can check it's legit ?

Comment: It'll be legit from an Apple store. Not to put you off StackExchange - because I think it's a perfectly valid question - but it might be the sort of thing I'd be shouting at Focusrite about; that's not exactly a budget piece of kit.

Comment: To make things clearer - what OS are you on & have you tried it over ASIO etc or only within the OS itself ... just in case a pro app can see it but not the raw coreaudio itself. Also, what DAW do you use?

Comment: Makes total sense. Unfortunately I won't have access to the gear until Monday, but from what I remember it was OSX Yosemite. I can't recall if it had any updates don is it's 10.10.1. On the macbook I could the sound card listed in AudioMIDI Setup and could access it from the coding environment I use ([PortAudio Python bindings](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)). I'll admit I'm a bit lost in the acronyms. I'm don't have a strong background in audio, simply access the devices through the driver. If I can see the device listed in Audio MIDI Setup, I can program it.

Comment: Ah, OK, I'm from the other angle - audio engineer, no coder ;-) If it's still on 10.10.1 I'd at least try 10.10.4 & see if it helps